OpenShift pipeline - How to allow only one Pipeline run at a time?
Hi I am new to OpenShift and from what I can see if I go to a Pipeline and select start twice, immediately two PipelineRuns will run in parallel. This will cause a error because both run's pods will try to access the same pvc and then the pods will get stuck in a bad state. The pods will have Event messages, "Volume is already used by pod(s)".
How can someone enforce that only one pipeline run at a time can run? Is it possible in OpenShift to have these pipeline runs queue up wait for existing pipeline to complete? Is there an OpenShift solution? If there are no out of the box solutions in OpenShift, are there standard workarounds or addons that exists?

As far as I know, there is no way to restrict only one pipielinerun run at a time.

Solution is to use volumeClaimTemplate in your pipeline-run. In this way each run gets its own persistent volume.
Put something like this in your pipeline run, or select volume template if you run from the console:
  workspaces:
    - name: workspace
      volumeClaimTemplate:
        spec:
          accessModes:
            - ReadWriteOnce
          resources:
            requests:
              storage: 1Gi
          volumeMode: Filesystem

Although it doesnt prohibit pipelines to go run in parallel, it will give them separate volumes - so no conflicts.

That would solve the persistent volume issue, but I don't want certain pipelines to run in parallel, but to queue up. So I was looking for that part. So far it looks like one can only add a locking mechanism in the pipeline code. One that would wait till lock is open but then that isn't queuing the runs. I haven't seen some queuing mechanism out there.
